# Searching in variable string for variable string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, loops, conditional-statements

```
        function searchChar()
        {
            var string = document.forms["myForm"]['bar'].value;
            var lookup = document.forms["myForm"]['bar2'].value;
            var strlok = new RegExp(lookup, "g");
            var result;

            for (i = 0; i < strlok.length; i++)
            {
                if (string.match(strlok))
                {
                    result = i;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = "No words found";
                }
            }
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;

        }
```

Now, this should be a counting function. I want to count how many times word or character in [bar2] appears in [bar]. First [bar] is where I write the string I want to be searched and second [bar2] wich serves as a descriptor for seached word. Now, the problem is that with this kind of loop and condition, im getting ,,undefined" all over the place, so I need to know, what am I doing wrong. I tried searching, no succes.. thanks in advance.

Comment: You're looping over `strlok.length` which does not make sense.

Comment: I assigned contents lookup value to strlok by using RegExp, or is it a mistake?

Comment: Sorry, missed it, I corrected the comment. What you have to do is simply `result = string.match(strlok)`. No need for loop. `result` will be an array if something is found and the length of an array will be the count. Otherwise it will be null.

Comment: Wow i cant belive it! Thank you soooo much, it works like a charm :)